# IntelliJ Plugin Development: LookupElement with class preview

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, intellij-plugin

For a custom language I created a [CompletionContributor](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/completion_contributor.html). Everything works fine. But I'm limited to the information I can display (only in the list or the bottom "advertisement" and only 1 line).

When trying to auto-complete on a java class name it will display more information on the selected line in a small side window. I would like to exploit that mechanism but I really don't know how it is done.

When looking at the options provided, I can use a custom LookupElementRenderer but there is no method in LookupElementPresentation related to the right window.

Any idea how it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to documentation popup which may be displayed if the corresponding setting (Setting->Editor->General->Code completion->Show the documentation popup in) is turned on?

If you want the feature to work for your language you have to use *lang.documentationProvider* extension point.

Comment: That's it, I tried the documentation provider but I did not notice the setting was turn off by default in the test environment..
Thanks a lot.